# I'm trying to use selenium code to refresh webpage regularly until button is clickable

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I have successfully created a script that navigates through the webpage to join the waitlist (with plenty of help from this community). This script works when the 'join waitlist' button is clickable, but sometimes the waitlist is not open there is no clickable button. How can I code this script to refresh the page continuously until the link is clickable, then proceed with the below script?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Python\Pycharm\MCattempt2\Drivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://v2.waitwhile.com/l/fostersbarbershop/list-view")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "join-waitlist")))
finally:
    element.click()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ww-name")))
finally:
    element.send_keys("geralt")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "phone01")))
finally:
    element.send_keys("5555555")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/public-landing- 
        page/main/div/div/public-confirm-page/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/button")))
finally:
    element.click()
```

Comment: While true then use a try and except to break out or driver.refresh().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment section use infinite loop to check whether element is clickable if not it will go to exception and refreshed page and continue infinite loop. if it finds clickable then it will click and break the infinite loop.

```
while True:
    try:
       element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ww-name")))
       element.click()
       break
    except:
       driver.refresh()
       continue
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the help! That was exactly what I needed. Now my script is working great. Very new at python so the community here is so helpful.